# Combining multiple power sources

Tags: power-supply, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply

Is it possible to combine the power of two power supplies to increase the total current and voltage

Comment: It depends on the power supply. Please update your question to be more specific. You should give the manufacturer and part number of your power supplies, and a link to any data-sheet or manual for the supplies, if possible. If the supplies are different voltages, then it will probably not be a good idea to connect them.

Comment: In above comment, I intended to type "not be a good idea to connect them in parallel."

Comment: @mkeith - Well **in series also is not a good idea**. Both power sources should have a **reverse parallel diode** to be connected in series. The reason is that both power supplies will never fire up at the same time, or one of them may power down due to overload while the other is still working. When this happens the active PSU carries current through the load and drives the shutted down PSU with negative voltage. If the shutted down PSU has a reverse parallel diode at its output, this diode will carry the current and the reverse voltage applied will be only -0.7V which is safe in most cases.

Comment: in order to talk about this in more detail, further information about the circuit is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course it is. This is how national grid systems work - multiple generators all feeding into one grid - and how battery banks are made up of series and parallel connections of batteries.

If by "power supplies" you mean mains-powered DC power supplies then these too can be series and parallel connected provided that they are designed to do so.

> Is it possible to combine the power of two power supplies to increase the total current and voltage?

Given two identical power supplies designed to be series or parallel connected then you can series them for double voltage at the same current **or** parallel them for double current at the same voltage.

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is possible.

e.g. it is possible two have some batteries connected in series or parallel, like [here](http://batteryuniversity.com/index.php/learn/article/serial_and_parallel_battery_configurations).

but if you have  controlled voltage sources and put them in parallel to get a higher output current this can (or will lead) to instabillity as the different voltage sources will always measure a slightly different voltage and as an effect try to compensate the "error". 
So there has to be an additional communication and control between the controlled voltage sources so that there is stability.

[Here](http://www.keysight.com/main/editorial.jspx?cc=DE&lc=ger&ckey=520808&nid=-11143.0.00&id=520808) you can read about one way to handle this.

> The output of each power supply can be set separately. The output voltage controls of one power supply should be set to the desired output voltage (CV); the other power supplies should be set for a slightly higher output voltage. The supplies with the higher output voltage setting will provide constant current output, and will drop their output voltage until it equals the output of the CV supply.

Answer (score -1):

In theory yes.

If you place of the same 2 batteries in series, you will double the voltage. Place them in parallel and you'll double the max amount of amps they can deliver.